# Find the unique value in column MS SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a set of data as below

```
number quantity
   1       4
   2       6
   3       7
   4       9
   2       1
   1       2
   5       4
```

I need to find the unique value in the column "number"

The output should look like this:

```
number quantity
3       7
4       9
5       4
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am using MS SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to go could be to have an aggregate query that counts the number of occurrences for each number use it in a subquery:

```
SELECT number, quantity
FROM   my_table
WHERE  number IN (SELECT   number
                  FROM     my_table
                  GROUP BY number
                  HAVING   COUNT(*) = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the inner query get all the distinct numbers, then join with again with the main table to get your expected results.

```
select o.* 
from mytable o , (select number
from mytable
group by number) dist
where o.number = dist.number
```

Answer (score 0):

If your column name is my_column in table my_table, the query is:

```
SELECT my_column, COUNT(*) as count
FROM my_table
GROUP BY my_column
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This will return all records that have duplicate my_column content, as well as how many times this content occurs in the database.

you can use below code for desire output:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(my_column), COUNT(*) as count
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY my_column
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT *
FROM   yourtable t1
WHERE  (SELECT Count(*)
        FROM   yourtable t2
        WHERE  t1.number = t2.number) = 1
```

Query in where clause will return number of occurrences of each `number` and checking it with 1 will return only those rows will have only one occurrence in table.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function like

```
select * from
(
select number, 
quantity,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY number ORDER BY number) AS rn
from table1
) tab where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
create table #TableName(number int, quantity int)
insert into #TableName values(1, 2)
insert into #TableName values(1, 4)
insert into #TableName values(2, 4)

SELECT number, quantity
FROM   #TableName
WHERE  number 
IN(SELECT number
          FROM #TableName
          GROUP BY number
          HAVING COUNT(NUMBER) = 1)
```